# Change OJDBC connect string in Eclipse

Tags: oracle, eclipse, jdbc

I am running on Windows 10 and am having difficulty creating a valid JDBC connection string to connect to my Oracle 21c Express from within Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (Kepler) with Window Builder and Database Development Plug-ins.

My database SID is XE and has a single container named XEPDB1 (yeah, I know, I'm lazy).

The user "admissions" which resides in the XEPDB1 container owns the database objects (tables, views indexes etc.) that I need to access through the UI.

The Eclipse project is named KVWR_Admissions

I tried to set up the jdbc connection in the Java EE perspective:
Window > Show View > Data Source Explorer > Database Connections
Having completed the fields:
SID:            XEPDB1    (Yes I do know XEPDB1 is NOT a SID)
Host:           localhost
Port Number:        1521
User Name:      admissions
Password:       (admissions password)
This generated the connection string:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEPDB1
This fails (ORA-12505 - Cannot connect to database. SID XEPDB1 is not registered with the listener at host localhost port 1521.). This makes sense as XEPDB1 is not the SID. I believe string should be:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1

Changing SID to XE (but leaving username and password credentials the same fails (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied). This also makes sense as the admissions user can only connect to XEPDB1 not XE (the command: sqlplus admissions/ with or without "@XE" at the end fails in exactly the same way).

Changing SID to XE, username to System and password to System's password succeeds with the connection string:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

So the simple solution would be to change the JDBC Connection URL for the XEPDB1 connector, but the field is not editable within the Driver Properties page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have run into [bug 536869](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536869) in the Eclipse issue tracker. This bug was filed in July 2018 and is still open and unresolved today.

The problem is that `XEPDB1` is a service name, not a SID. When using a service name, the connection URL needs to end with `/servicename`, not `:servicename`. But the Data Source Explorer dialog doesn't let you change this, it stubbornly insists on using the colon in the connection URL.

Helpfully, the linked bug also includes a workaround:

> Set `USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_<listener>=on` in listener.ora on server side.
> Where `<listener>` is the name of your listner [sic].